# recursive directory svn move shell script

Tags: svn, bash

I want to rename all nested directories named "foo" to "bar" - I've tried the following with no joy:

```
find */ -name 'foo' | xargs svn move {} 'bar' \;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will attempt to move each `foo` to `pwd`/bar and passes `svn move` too many arguments.  Here's what I would do:

```
find . -depth -type d -name 'foo' -print | while read ; do echo svn mv $REPLY `dirname $REPLY`/bar ; done
```

You can remove the `echo` to have it actually perform the operation. The above works under the assumption that you don't have spaces in your filenames.

Comment: You might want to `sort --reverse` the `find` results before the `while read`. To avoid renaming a nested directory **after** renaming its' parent... Also have a `-type d` in the find for good measure.

Comment: @Chen - good suggestions. Added `-depth` to handle the nested case and `-type d` "for good measure."

Answer (score 1):

You could use bash to visit manually the directory tree using a post-order walk:

```
#!/bin/bash

visit() {
local file
for file in $1/*; do 
    if [ -d "$file" ]; then
        visit "$file";
        if [[ $file =~ /foo$ ]]; then
            svn move $file ${file%foo}bar;
        fi                  
    fi
done
}

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
exit
fi

visit $1
```

This code doesn't have any infinite loops detection, but should work in simple cases.